# Heroku Cedar Stack and command heroku run console

Tags: heroku, console, sinatra, irb, cedar

In my old Ruby 1.9.2 Sinatra apps running on Bamboo stack, heroku console provided a shell that not only initialized Active Record but also logged to a history file in my .heroku directory.

After moving to Heroku Cedar stack and using Ruby 1.9.3, I found heroku run console did not load any of my Active Record models. I fixed that by writing a small ruby script to initialize Active Record and load my models.

I execute this using the awkward heroku run 'bundle exec irb -r ./console'

This IRB console fires up fine and gives me access to my model data, but no history is logged.

1) Why is heroku run console so neutered?
2) How can I get my console sessions to log to history?

Please?

Thanks

Comment: I think keroku run console was made mainly for RoR apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to your `Procfile`:

```
console: bundle exec irb -r ./console
```

Keeping the history is not easily possible, as it will spin up a dyno for every new invocation (cedar stack doesn't keep the history for Rails console, either). You could try using [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap) to keep your history on the local machine.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks Konstantin, I will try using a Procfile. So far, it all works without one.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/console):

> You can use heroku console as a stand-in for Rails’s script runner, to
>   run one-time commands directly from the command line

and

> Without an argument, `heroku console` launches an interactive console
>   similar to `irb` or the Rails `script/console` command

`run console` is aimed at running the Rails console, or `irb`.